# How to stop Safari from saving passwords for certain page?

Tags: safari, password, login

I am programming a certain webpage with login and Safari is asking me if I want to save my password every time I try it (I have to try it a number of times, because it's the point of the webpage).

Can I stop Safari from saving passwords for just this webpage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could remove the password for that website right now by going to Safari > Preferences > Passwords > remove the needed website. Then, sign in again and choose Never for this website option when prompted to save password.